# Issue with Deezer paginated call for method Artist/Top

Tags: deezer

Is there any possibility of knowing the total number of items for the method Artist/Top without fetching all metadata?

Currently if you call: http://api.deezer.com/artist/27/top will return **"total": 5**

However if you set the limit parameter the total will be the number of returned items

http://api.deezer.com/artist/27/top?limit=22 returns **"total": 22**

For other methods the **total** field will return the total number of items that can be fetched.

Comment: We know that we have some pagination issues, we are currently working on it, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Fred_Dzr thank you for your fast reply, can you please confirm me if this is only for this method or are there any other methods as well having similar issues?

Comment: All the methods where you can have tracks or albums, in a pagination. All will be fixed of course.